# How to setup express and node into an existing front-end only Angular 2 project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

I have a current front-end only Angular 2 application using the Angular-CLI and NPM. I want visitors to be able to send me emails through the contact form.

For this I obviously need a back-end, express and node, in which I have no experience in using.

I need to intergrate express and node into my app but I dont know how to do this correctly.

I have found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211473/how-to-add-node-to-an-existing-angular-2-typescript-asp-net-core-project) similar question on SO but its not relevant to my situation.

Other tutorials only show how to scaffold a MEAN stack app not intergrate the backend after the front end has been built.

**What I would like to know**:

- How do I set up my Angular 2 App to use express and node for the back end?
- What are the relevant files I need?
- Can I do this by using the Angular-CLI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to setup a project that is built using angular-cli to use a nodejs/express backend is to simple create an express project that serves up a directory. In your client project, if it has been created using the angular-cli, you should be able to just type in `ng build` and it will compile everything into a `dist` directory.

From there, you can create an express server that serves up that `dist` directory like so:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});
```

The most simple server you could build would probably something like

```
var express = require('express')
var path = require('path');

var app = express()

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});
```

This will intercept all routes and redirect them to the `index.html` file in the `dist/` folder that was created.

For more information on how to set this up and some more advanced settings, check out these links:

- http://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html
- https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli

Just think about the `dist/` folder as static files that will be served over an express server, and because routing and everything is handled through angular, you'll be set.